# HTML Sidebar Appears at bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

On one of my pages the sidebar is at the bottom, beneath the content, but on other pages the sidebar is on the right, which is good.

The site is here [RomaniaRelocations.com](http://RomaniaRelocations.com)

I also have some JavaScript on it. but in my css at the sidebar I have this:

`.sidebar{
    padding:0px;
    }`

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to have the sidebar and content in the same `.row` element  `<div class="row"><div class="sidbar col-md-4"></div><div class="content col-md-8"></div></div>`

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I added `<div class="row"> sidebar </div>` and it didn't change anything.

Comment: you have to put BOTH divs in the SAME `.row`. You have them in separate `.row` elements now. Check @pralhad's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DIV`of LHS falling outside of `row`.

> ```
> <div class="row">
>     <div class="sidbar col-md-4">This is your LHS</div>
>     <div class="content col-md-8">This is right pane</div>
> </div>
> ```

You can also apply [float:left] to the  if you have already not applied it.

Comment: I added the code you written here Sonar. I have this now: `<div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-md-4 sidebar">
        <div class="content col-md-8">
         <div style="border-top:2px solid #b91305;" class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Romania-Relocations/384764515064535" data-width="340" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>` Now it shown a blue background behind the facebook page, and the page is still at the bottom. Thank you.

Comment: It seems you are mentioning `row` div twice. You will also need to close `sidebar` div as well.

<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4 sidebar"> </div>
    <div class="content col-md-8"> 
        <div style="border-top:2px solid #b91305;" class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Romania-Relocations/384764515064535" data-width="340" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false"></div> 
    </div> 
</div>

Comment: please look at the structure of the code given in my answer.

Comment: If I delete 2 more `row` div then at the bottom of the page it gets messy.

Comment: @Site - I just gone through the source code of your website - you will need to change many more things. Here are few observations 1. Head tag being used inappripriately 2. DIVs are appearing in <head> tag - which is wrong. Perhaps you will need to go through some HTML basic tutorial. Please let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: #2, I deleted the div in the <head> tag. For observation 1, I cannot see what's wrong with the <head> tag. Will you be kind to help me out Pralhad? if you have time and want to help me of course.

Comment: Ya - I have time. Why dont you look at the page - http://romaniarelocations.com/contact.php . Its structure is perfect. This page has followed exactly same structure as its given in my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Pralhad for the help. It's fixed now. Greatly appreciate your time and help. Have a great day!